docker image is local ,why docker file still pull from remote
macos sonama14.5
Docker version 27.1.1, build 6312585
➜  fc docker images | grep fc
fc-image                           latest              01b6817436f0   8 days ago      95.2MB
aliyunfc/runtime-custom.debian10   3.1.0               39d6b3ffdea1   6 months ago    1.94GB
aliyunfc/runtime-custom.debian10   latest              26267d5ebd1f   11 months ago   1.55GB


➜  fc docker build -t fc-debian10-php83:1.0 .
[+] Building 6.0s (1/2)                                                                              docker:desktop-linux
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                 0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 1.65kB                                                                               0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/aliyunfc/runtime-custom.debian10:3.1.0                                    6.0s

why still pull from remote ?

A Docker image's name always has a registry host name associated with it.  You might be seeing the default Docker Hub registry host name in that message, but it's not actually contacting Docker Hub.  Are you sure it's contacting a remote server?  Also see "naming to docker.io", explanation and prevention?
